# What is wrong with this particular AngularJS code?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I just learning AngularJS via several online websites after having familiarized myself with, and learned, basic JS, HTML, and CSS. I found those 3 fairly simple to learn but am having a bit of an issue with AngularJS. I am really just at the beginning but have a question as to why a code that I am inputting is not returning the desired result. I have two windows (or files... I am not sure what the correct vocab is here) open. A js one titled main.js and an index file titled index.html. In main.js I have:

```
    var app= angular.module('myApp'),[])

    app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
      $scope.person = {
        name: "Papa Bear"
      };
    });
```

In the index file I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
    <script src='js/main.js'></script>
    </head>
  <body> 
  <h2> Hi there </h2>
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
  {{ person.name }}
</div>
  </body>
  <html>
```

The "Hi there" displays just fine. But the {{ person.name }} which (I am fairly certain) should return: Papa Bear simply shows up as literally "{{ person.name }}". Where is the error in my code that it is not connecting person.name to Papa Bear?

Comment: it's not clear if you have included the `angular` script in your index file? It doesn't look like you have from what is posted.

Comment: Check your browser's JS / error console. You have a typo in your `module` line, it should be `angular.module('myApp', [])` (you have an extra `)` after the module name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, just like kaveman pointed out, you have to have the angular script included for it to work. Try adding this to the head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And see if that works.

**Edit**
Also, I just noticed (thanks to Bhojendra Nepal), this:

```
var app= angular.module('myApp'),[])
```

Should be:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

angular.module takes the app name as the first argument, and an array of dependencies as the second argument in order to create a new angular module. Without the second argument of an array of dependencies, it returns an existing angular module of that name.

So optionally, instead of assigning your module to a variable, you could do:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController',function($scope){
    $scope.person = {
        name: "Papa Bear"
    };
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: also remove extra `)`

Comment: So I always need to add in a <script src="whater"> </script> to connect to an AngularJS program? How do I know which to use specifically each time? Or is there one that I can always use?

Comment: You always need to have the angular library included, either via the CDN link, or via a copy of the library on your server. Serving your own copy might be helpful if you minify/concatenate your angular files, but using a CDN has the benefit that the user may have visited a site that used the CDN too, so the library may have already been cached. So, they won't need to download it at all and they could just use the version from their cache, speeding up page load time.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/y17Lehqg/

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
      $scope.person = {
        name: "Papa Bear"
      };
    });